# Refernce Solution Fails with NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, physics, application

I'm trying to crosscheck a solution of an ODE that is already implemented in Python. In Python I'm using a Newton iteration together with periodic boundary conditions to solve my ODE. In order to get a meaningful "reference solution" I want to solve the ODE with a completely different method, namely Mathematica's built in routines.

The ODE I'm trying to solve is the extension of well known constraint condition for one dimensional Bose gases [1]. The well known constraint condition comes with an analytical solution and the solution of the extended version has to converge against the analytical solution at the boundaries in my example below. (Note that the below defined problem satisfies periodic boundary conditions!)

The problem that I'm encountered is the following. While the problem is perfectly solvable with my solver in Python, Mathematica seem to have troubles while solving the BVP problem I formulated which should be equvivalent to my formulation with periodic BC. This of course can indicate that my other solver does not work properly, but it was already crosschecked with another 3D solver and yielded good results.
So I'm maybe missunderstanding the function of NDSolve or have to declare an accurate method for solving BVPs (currently I'm using Version 12.0). Especially I would not expect any kind of singularity as Mathematica states in the following example which can be a hint on a numerical problem.
So I would be thankful if someone can tell me if this is a problem with my code in Mathematica.

Anyhow here is a minimal example of my code that throws me "1/0" errors when it is calling NDSolve.

```
(* Box Length *)
xmax = 40 * 10^(-9); 
xmin = -40 * 10^(-9);
L = xmax - xmin; (*interval for a standard period, not affected from cutoff *)

(*extended interval in order to apply cutoff and damp the dynamic in \
the density at the boundary. *)
Simmin = 20 * xmin; 
Simmax = 20 * xmax;

(* System Parameters *)
m = 1.444668987942*10^(-25);
h = 1.0545718176461565*10^(-34);
\[Omega] = 1000;

(* Varring Parameters *)
as = 5.2*10^(-9);
A = 1*10^9;
k = 2;


(* Densities *)
Step[x_] = 1/(1 + Exp[-50000000*(x)]) - 0.5;
Cutoff[x_] := Step[x - 8*xmin] + Step[-x + 8*xmax]

Plot[Cutoff[x], {x, Simmin, Simmax}, PlotLabel -> "Cutoff"]
\[Psi][x_] :=  A/3 * (Sin[k*x*2*Pi/L] + 2) *Cutoff[x] 
Plot[\[Psi][x], {x, Simmin, Simmax}, PlotLabel -> "Denisity \[Psi]"]


(* analytical Sol *)
Sal[x_] := Sqrt[h/(m \[Omega]) * Sqrt[1 + 2*as*\[Psi][x]]]
Plot[Sal[x], {x, 20*xmin, 20*xmax}, PlotLabel -> "analytical Sol", 
 PlotRange -> Automatic]


(* extended Eq *)
ext = D[\[Sigma][x], x, x] *\[Psi][x] + 
    D[\[Sigma][x], x] * D[\[Psi][x], x] - \[Sigma][x]^(-1) *
     D[\[Sigma][x], x]^2 *\[Psi][x] + \[Sigma][x]^(-1)*\[Psi][x] - ( 
      m^2 * \[Omega]^2 / h^2)  * \[Sigma][x]^3 * \[Psi][x] + 
    2 as \[Sigma][x]^(-1) * \[Psi][x]^2 == 0;
bcs = {\[Sigma][Simmin] == Sal[Simmin],  \[Sigma][Simmax] == 
    Sal[Simmax]};
s = NDSolve[{ext, bcs}, \[Sigma], {x, Simmin, Simmax}];
(*Plot[Evaluate[\[Sigma][x]/.s],{x,Simmin,Simmax},PlotStyle\[Rule]\
Automatic, PlotLabel\[Rule]"extended"]*)
```

[1] L. Salasnich, and A. Parola and L. Reatto, ”Effective wave equations for the dynamics of cigar- shaped and disk-shaped Bose condensates”, Phys. Rev. A 65 (4) 043614 (6pages), 2002

Comment: Are you sure the problem itself is correct? I've tested with `FiniteElement` method, finite difference method, shooting method via `ParametricNDSolveValue` and built-in `Shooting`, none of them gives reasonable result.

Comment: There is open pdf on   https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0201395 with paper cited.

Comment: I solved the problem finally. It turned out that the problems initially were not equivalent. Thanks for your help, this topic can be considered as closed.